# How do I change the format of digit inputs

Tags: javascript

Basically, I want to change a person input from 0######### to (0#)########, the event im using is onblur

```
        function numberChange(){
            var check = document.getElementById("number").value;
            var regCheck = /^[0-9]+$/; 
            if (check != 10 || !regCheck)
            {
                alert("Please input your 10 digit mobile number")
                return false;
            }
            else if (check == 10 || regCheck)
            {

                return true;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `regCheck` should be `^\(0\d\)\d{8}$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zK0rO0/1)

**Update :**

This regex validates the number of characters, you can omit length check in your code :

```
function numberChange(){
    var check = document.getElementById("number").value;
    var re = new RegExp(/^\(0\d\)\d{8}$/);
    if (re.test(check)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert("Please input your 10 digit mobile number")
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will check for 10 digits, first number is zero, and that all inputs are digits. Once all of that passes the code will add the '(' & ')' to it. This approach gives specific errors depending on how the user incorrectly entered the number.

```
<html>
<body>

Phone number: <input type="text" id="number" onblur="checkNumber()">

<script>
function checkNumber() {
    var x = document.getElementById("number").value;

    // Check for 10 digits.
    if(x.length != 10) {
        alert('The number must be 10 digits.');
        return false;
    }

    // Make sure the first digit is 0.
    if(x.charAt(0) != 0) {
        alert('The first digit must be 0.');
        return false;
    }

    // Make sure all digits are numbers and not characters.
    if(isNaN(x) == true) {
        alert('All digits must be numbers.');
        return false;
    }

    // If here then everything else passed so add the '(' and ')' to the number.
    document.getElementById("number").value = '(0' + x.charAt(1) + ')' + x.substring(2, 10);

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```